# flag queue: "very low quality" disposal choice: possible bug

Tags: support, bug

Two answers appeared in my flag queue today (https://english.stackexchange.com/tools/flagged). Both answers were marked "Low answer quality score". I found it strange that one offered me the "very low quality" disposal choice and the other did not:

> I am flagging this answer because
>
> - it needs ♦ moderator attention
>
> > - not an answer
> >   This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.
> > - *very low quality*
> >   *This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.*
> > - invalid flag
> >   I do not agree with the existing flags on this answer, they are incorrect and should be ignored.
> > - other
>
> - it is spam
> - it is not welcome in our community

versus:

> I am flagging this answer because
>
> - it needs ♦ moderator attention
>
> > - not an answer
> >   This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.
> > - invalid flag
> >   I do not agree with the existing flags on this answer, they are incorrect and should be ignored.
> > - other
>
> - it is spam
> - it is not welcome in our community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow me to quote [an answer on meta.stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110754/215040):

> We now suppress the "very low quality" option. It is only available on closed questions or **posts with a score less than 1**. *(emphasis added)*

Based on the above, I think this is expected behavior.  My guess is that the first question was rated zero or less, while the second question was rated one or higher.

Can you confirm that this is the case?

Comment: Thank you, that must explain what I saw. I cannot say what scores the two posts had, but I did just now observe the identical behavior with a different post having 0 votes. When I clicked the flag button, I saw the "very low quality" choice. When I upvoted the post and then clicked the flag button again, the choice was gone.